# Listing most common suffixes using Python

Tags: python, for-loop, dictionary

I am trying to write a function that will find the most common suffixes in a list or text file. I am having trouble iterating through the list or file and adding the suffixes to the dictionary with a counter for each time they appear.

```
file = open('suffix.txt', 'r')

def suffix(text):
    suffixList = {}
    count = 0
    read = file.readlines()
    Suffix = ""
    for line in read:
        line = line.strip('\n') #I am trying to strip the line character
        line = line[-3:] #Here I am trying to find 3-letter suffixes
        if line not in suffixList:
            suffixList[Suffix] = [line] #I want to add the suffix to the dic
            count += 1 # I want to add a counter for each suffix 


return suffixList
print (suffixList)


suffix(file)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, `return` should go inside the function. Second, `Suffix` in your code never changes, and for that reason, You won't achieve your goal. Third, `count` increases for every line no matter what suffix is.

```
file = open('suffix.txt', 'r')

def find_suffix(text):
    suffixList = {}
    for line in file.readlines():
        line = line.strip('\n')
        suffix = line[-3:]
        if suffix not in suffixList:
            suffixList[suffix] = 1
        else:
            suffixList[suffix] += 1

    return suffixList

find_suffix(file)
```

First time suffix occurs, add it to the list and set count to 1. Every time suffix reappears, just increase counter.

Comment: Thank you Fejs, this works best. I didn't think about the fact that suffix would never change

Answer (score 1):

You may use [`collections.Counter()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) with *list comprehension* as:

```
>>> from collections import Counter  
>>> my_name_list = ['Mr XYZ', 'Ms ABC', 'Dr 123', 'Er Hello Sir', 'Mr PQR', 'Dr XYZ']
>>> Counter(name[-3:] for name in my_name_list)
Counter({'XYZ': 2, '123': 1, 'Sir': 1, 'ABC': 1, 'PQR': 1})
#         ^ XYZ twice in list            ^ ABC once in list
```